# How to solve this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql-server

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`marketplace`.`mg_nbmp_review`, CONSTRAINT `FK__nbmp_vendor` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES `('marketplace/vendor')` (`vendor_id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO
>   `mg_nbmp_review` (`vendor_id`, `vendor_name`, `customer_id`,
>   `customer_name`, `customer_email`, `rating`, `review_comment`,
>   `reviewed_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2015-04-08 11:51:58')

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('vendorreview/review')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('vendorreview/review')} (
    `review_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vendor_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vendor_name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rating` ENUM('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
    `review_comment` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reply` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reviewed_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
    INDEX `FK__nbmp_vendor` (`vendor_id`),
    INDEX `FK__customer_entity` (`customer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__nbmp_vendor` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES {$this->getTable('marketplace/vendor')} (`vendor_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__customer_entity` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES {$this->getTable('customer/entity')} (`entity_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COMMENT='Vendor Review Table'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Where i m wrong?

Comment: similar Question answer is here [integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063652/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)

Answer (score 1):

First you should not drop table as describe above answer & this error shows that you are trying to insert a value to vendor_id which is not in its master table marketplace/vendor's vendor_id column value. It means Foreign key violation. you are inserting a wrong value which does not refers to any value in master table.