# MYSQL and PHP: How to add mysql constraint but proceed anyway if not found

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have a code where I need a foreign key check disabled when updating.  But I still need it to check for the foreign key but proceed anyways if the key is not found.  The installation keeps breaking due to this.

```
$installthis->run("
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('sweets/results')}`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SWEETS_RESULTS_SWEET_ID_SWEETS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`sweet_id`)
      REFERENCES `{$this->getTable('sweets/sweets')}` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('sweets/results_values')}`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SWEETS_RESULTS_VALUES_RESULT_ID_SWEETS_RESULTS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`)
      REFERENCES `{$this->getTable('sweets/results')}` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
");
```

What do I need to change or add if I want it to proceed?

Edit:
The error states that

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`sweets_database`.`sweets_results`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_SWEETS_RESULTS_SWEET_ID_SWEETS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`sweet_id`)
>   REFERENCES `sweets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE), query
>   was: INSERT INTO `sweets_results` (`customer_id`, `created_time`,
>   `update_time`) VALUES (?, '2018-11-02 05:35:24', '2018-11-02
>   05:35:24')

Comment: It would be useful if you provide the error.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063652/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)