# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row in Laravel9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-9

I have an integrity constraint violation when I run the `php artisan db:seed` command in Laravel 9.

**Error**

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hunger-db`.`restaurants`, CONSTRAINT `restaurants_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)")

**setup_users_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->tinyInteger('role_as')->default('0');
        $table->tinyInteger('gender')->default('0');
        $table->string('date_of_birth')->default('1999/9/9');
        $table->rememberToken();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**setum_restaurants_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('img_src');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('minimum_order_amount');
        $table->string('working_hours_open');
        $table->string('working_hours_close');
        $table->string('delivery_time');
        $table->string('delivery_fee');
        $table->boolean('status')->default('0');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->default('1');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**User Model**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone',
    ];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);
    }
}
```

**Restaurant Model**

```php
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'img_src',
        'description',
    ];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have in user.php`$this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);` but also have the same in restaurant.php `$this->belongsTo(User::class);`
First should be in user.php `$this->hasMany(Restaurant::class);`

Comment: I tried it and still the same problem </3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some things to change here

#### setup_restaurants_table

I don't see with good eyes `user_id` with default 1, maybe is better to define the value when restaurant is created or manually assign it to user 1.

```
Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        ...
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('CASCADE');
});
```

**After DB changes run** `php artisan migrate:fresh`

#### User.php

Should change relation to `hasMany` Restaurants

```
public function restaurants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Restaurant::class);
}
```

#### Seeding

Also ensure your DB seeding is correct, I mean creating user first and then restaurant, set `user_id` with an existing value.

Maybe creating a restaurant like this:

```
$user = User::factory()
            ->hasRestaurants(3)
            ->create();
```

**If any factory change run** `php artisan db:seed`

Can also see [Factory Retationship Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#factory-relationships)

Comment: The problem was fixed when I changed the Seeding, creating user first and then restaurant! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Check the **user_id** you have added to the **restaurants** table. Make sure it exists in the **Users** table. Maybe my english not enough to tell you, can check another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063682/18527136) for the problem.