# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (the record exists in the other table)

Tags: mysql, laravel

First of all, I have checked the answers from this link and none have helped me. I have checked everything you say and it is correct.

[Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063652/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)

I have two identical tables, one will be used for the records of the month and the other will be used for history.

My problem comes when I want to pass the data from the month table to the history table. It gives me the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails credit_records_historic`, CONSTRAINT` credit_record_historic_id_manager_foreign `FOREIGN KEY (`id_manager`) REFERENCES` managers `(`id`)

Here is the code of my monthly table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `credit_records` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_client` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `value` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `id_type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `observations` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_terminal` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_manager` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_institution` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `sended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `received` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `credit_record_id_client_foreign` (`id_client`),
    KEY `credit_record_id_user_foreign` (`id_user`),
    KEY `credit_record_id_type_foreign` (`id_type`),
    KEY `credit_record_id_terminal_foreign` (`id_terminal`),
    KEY `credit_record_id_manager_foreign` (`id_manager`),
    KEY `credit_records_id_institution_foreign` (`id_institution`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_id_client_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_client`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_id_manager_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manager`) REFERENCES `managers` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_id_terminal_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_terminal`) REFERENCES `terminals` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_id_type_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_type`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_id_user_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_records_id_institution_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_institution`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2124 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I have checked that the manager with id 5 exists, and it does. And even in the two tables there are records with that manager id.

Here is the code of my history table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `credit_records_historic` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_client` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `value` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `id_type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `observations` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_terminal` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_manager` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_institution` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `sended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `received` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `credit_record_historic_id_client_foreign` (`id_client`),
    KEY `credit_record_historic_id_user_foreign` (`id_user`),
    KEY `credit_record_historic_id_type_foreign` (`id_type`),
    KEY `credit_record_historic_id_terminal_foreign` (`id_terminal`),
    KEY `credit_record_historic_id_manager_foreign` (`id_manager`),
    KEY `credit_records_historic_id_institution_foreign` (`id_institution`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_client_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_client`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_manager_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manager`) REFERENCES `managers` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_terminal_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_terminal`) REFERENCES `terminals` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_type_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_type`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_user_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `credit_records_historic_id_institution_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_institution`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2013 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Thanks

---

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`credit_records_historic`, CONSTRAINT `credit_record_historic_id_manager_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manager`) REFERENCES `managers` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `credit_records_historic` (`id_client`, `id_user`, `value`, `id_type`, `observations`, `id_terminal`, `id_manager`, `id_institution`, `sended`, `received`, `date`) values (1, 4, 100, 11, Nemo et dolores quis. Omnis doloremque dignissimos blanditiis officiis tenetur. Ab itaque voluptatibus est quia., 1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2022-02-17 17:15:30))

Table Managers:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `managers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surnames` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_role` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `managers_username_unique` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `managers_email_unique` (`email`),
  KEY `managers_id_lang_foreign` (`id_lang`),
  KEY `managers_id_role_foreign` (`id_role`),
  CONSTRAINT `managers_id_lang_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_lang`) REFERENCES `langs` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `managers_id_role_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_role`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And the insert:

```
INSERT INTO `managers` 
            (`id`, `name`, `surnames`, `username`, `slug`, `email`, 
            `password`, 
            `id_lang`, `id_role`, `state`, 
            `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted`, `deleted_at`) 
VALUES (5, 'q', 'q', 'q@q.q', 'q', 'q@q.q', 
        '$2y$10$omstJzdZPxt4NKNEBSLXwuOGFW7RP286NM7pFLPifFSpSuv.uj0Pu', 
        1, 2, 1, 
        '2022-01-20 13:12:49', '2022-01-20 13:12:49', 0, NULL));
```

The insert fails:

```
insert into credit_records_historic 
        (id_client, id_user, value, id_type, 
        observations, 
        id_terminal, id_manager, id_institution, sended, received, date) 
values (1, 4, 100, 11, 
        Nemo et dolores quis. Omnis doloremque dignissimos blanditiis officiis tenetur. Ab itaque voluptatibus est quia., 
        1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2022-02-17 17:15:30))
```

I'm using laravel

My code:

```
    CreditRecord::query()
            ->where('id','>', '0')
            ->each(function ($old_record) {
                $new_record = $old_record->replicate();
                $new_record->setTable('credit_records_historic');
                $new_record->save();
                $old_record->delete();
            });
```

Comment: Does the error message you are seeing contain the SQL that is being executed to generate this error? It normally does. If so please show us the COMPLETE error message

Comment: First thing to remember in these situations is: MySQL does not get bored and decide to throw an error at you, the error is real, all you have to do is find it

Comment: And as the error is about an id field which references the `managers` table I would have expected to see a create table for that table as well. Also some data from that table to prove that the id in question actually exists

Comment: There would seem to be some obvious Quotes missing in that query!!!!!

Comment: Can you show us a print of the query that  you are running that is causing the issue

Comment: RiggsFolly i update the questions adding the table managers and the insert for the manager with id 5

Comment: the insert is in the error.

Comment: So the insert in the error is MISSING `'` around the string values!!! I wanted to see the Actuall query you were running in case that was something the error message had stripped off.